# How to reference two tables using hasOne with sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Considering these 3 models generated by sequelize-auto:

```
sequelize.define('users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        first: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        last: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'users',
        underscored: true,
        timestamps: false
    });

sequelize.define('groups', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        parent_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            references: {
                model: 'groups',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'groups',
        underscored: true,
        timestamps: false
});

sequelize.define('user_groups', {
        group_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            references: {
                model: 'groups',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'users',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'user_groups',
        underscored: true,
        timestamps: false
    });
```

I was expecting hasOne statements to be generated but I had to specify them like so:

```
user_groups.hasOne(orm.models.users, { foreignKey: "id" });
user_groups.hasOne(orm.models.groups, { foreignKey: "id" });
```

Also consider the following data in tables:

```
users (id, first, last):
1, John, Doe

group (id, parent_id):
1, NULL
2, NULL
3, NULL
4, NULL

user_groups (group_id, user_id):
1, 1
4, 1
```

Doing this query:

```
sequelize.findAll("user_groups", {
    attributes: ["*"],
    raw: true,
    include: [{
        model: models.users,
    }]
});
```

I get the following results:

```
[ { group_id: 4,
    user_id: 1,
    'user.id': null,
    'user.first': null,
    'user.last': null },
  { group_id: 1,
    user_id: 1,
    'user.id': 1,
    'user.first': 'John',
    'user.last': 'Doe' } ]
```

This clearly shows that sequelize is using group_id for the user_id relation.

How can I specify a relation that links the user_groups relations to their respective tables in order to be able to associate a user to many groups?

I am also very curious as how the "references" key in the models definition is supposed to work as the documentation is inexistant on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the referenced data using these associations:

```
groups.hasMany(orm.models.user_groups);
user_groups.belongsTo(orm.models.groups, {foreignKey: "group_id", as: "group"});

users.hasMany(orm.models.user_groups);
user_groups.belongsTo(orm.models.users, {foreignKey: "user_id", as: "user"});
```

And the following query:

```
sequelize.findAll("user_groups", {
    attributes: ["*"],
    raw: true,
    include: [
        { model: users, foreignKey: "user_id", as: "user", attributes: ["first", "last"] }
    ]
});
```

With the expected results:

```
[ { group_id: 4,
    user_id: 1,
    'user.first': 'John',
    'user.last': 'Doe' },
  { group_id: 1,
    user_id: 1,
    'user.first': 'John',
    'user.last': 'Doe' } ]
```

Comment: How is it that you were so stuck that you asked a question yet were able to answer it yourself just 18 minutes later? In addition, there are plenty of references examples in the documentation. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/

Comment: Writing the question and looking at similar questions made me so very focused on the problem I had that I found the answer quickly. It often happens to me.

The documentation still doesn't explain the references clause in the models. If it does please point me to it.

Comment: Check out the table under the 'define' method for an explanation of references. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out to me, I was trying to find it in the models section of the documentation.

It seems to define foreign keys and what to CASCADE, etc. Does it have anything to do with setting hasOne, belongsTo etc. associations?

Maybe this is a whole other question for stack exchange. I will figure it out probably in 18 minutes.